# swift parse json as per maintaining order

Tags: ios, json, swift

Suppose i have json string in which there is a json array called data.
The array holds json object of user profile data for example name,age,gender etc.

Now  want to parse that json object as per order, for example if the object is

```
{
    "name": "sample name",
    "age": "30",
    "gender": "male"

}
```

i want to parse the list as ordered like `name,age,gender` but with ios,when i convert the json object as dictionary , the order is changed,i know dictionary is not ordered so what is the the alternative to achieve this?

its a third party api so i dont have any hand on it,we have done it in android with linked hash map,but really stuck in swift , the last thing i would want to do is parse with regular expression.

im parsing the json in following way :

```
var rootData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
  if let val = fromList["data"] {

let dataNode = val as! [[String:Any]]

for row in dataNode {


 for (key,keyVal) in row {
//here the key is not in order.because when we cast it as dictionary the order gets changed.


   }

}
```

For android we have achieved to do this with following function :

```
public ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> parseJsonArrayList(String odata, String arrayName) {
ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> mylist = new ArrayList<>();

try {
JSONObject e = new JSONObject(odata);
JSONArray data = e.getJSONArray(arrayName);

for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); ++i) {
JSONObject v = data.getJSONObject(i);
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(100, 0.75f, false);
Iterator keys = v.keys();

while(keys.hasNext()) {
String key = String.valueOf(keys.next());
//gph.log("debug4", key);
map.put(key, v.getString(key));
//gph.log("debug4", v.getString(key));
}

mylist.add(map);
}
} catch (JSONException var10) {
var10.printStackTrace();
}

return mylist;
}
```

Comment: As you said, dictionaries have no order so why do you need to keep order? The order is irrelevant.

Comment: As i said its user profile data and i need to show it as per the order, so name first ,age then,then gender. it would look odd if in user profile age is first,then name then gender.

There could be millions of reason ,so question is not why,question is how.

Comment: Rather than a dictionary use a custom struct or class

Comment: Problem is the keys of the response is dynamic and can be changed, so can not use object mapping.

and whenever i cast the root json object with dictionary , i see the internal data nodes vaues are already changed.

so if i go rootobject ,then take the data object,iterate over it,and print the each object ,the key values are changed already.

Comment: If the keys are dynamic how do you know the order? You should add a concrete example with input and expected output.

Comment: It seems we’re not getting exactly what you’re trying to do. Perhaps you could add an example of how you’re using the linked hash in Android to do what you want?

Comment: say im parsing the json objetc like this

var rootData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
  if let val = fromList["data"] {
            
let dataNode = val as! [[String:Any]]

for row in dataNode {

   
 for (key,keyVal) in row {

  //here the key is not in order.because when we cast it as dictionary the //order gets changed.all i want is to parse the key as its order in the //response,ill add the android code later

   }

}
      
      
            
        }

Comment: @ShofiqulAlam Please update your question.Also post your JSON response.

Comment: updated accordingly.

Comment: @ShofiqulAlam.What about sorting the dict according to Alphabetical order.? You can also change the key of the value while sorting...

Comment: no,as i said,i need order not sorted.For example i may need to show name first,and age later,but with alphabetical order,age will come first,name second.

beside in api,the order can be configured from web panel,and key can be created dynamically with its value, so parsing the key as its order in the json string is the only requirement.

Comment: @ShofiqulAlam can you share your full json format. which one right : `{
    "name": "sample name",
    "age": "30",
    "gender": "male"

}` or `[{
    "name": "sample name",
    "age": "30",
    "gender": "male"

}]`

Comment: its just sample,could be lie { "data" : [{ "name": "sample name", "age": "30", "gender": "male" } ]}

Comment: How do you imagine to use that? Since there might be Floats, Ints and arrays. It will result in some weird mess you will end up solving for each place where you want to use it. Why not to keep track of API changes and adjust your mapping? Hovewer there exists a type of Dictionary which keeps the order of insertion. It is called `DictionaryLiteral`. I guess you do not want to create your own json serializer as the result object cannot be casted to this type, at least I don't know how. I strongly recommend to keep track of API changes.

Comment: Luzo,its actually can be created dynamically from web app.Say admin can create a new field and put value in it,and result json will include that ,so object mapping is absolutely not possible .

and for the record,we can check if the value is string and show it.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t try to order the dictionary. Instead create an array of the keys in the order you desire:

```
let keys = [“name”, “age”, “gender”]
```

Then access the dictionary with them:

```
for key in keys {
    let value = dict[key]
    // Present the value.
}
```

That will ensure the order you expect.

Comment: i can not, cause the keys are dynamic from the server and could be changed so manually creating an array of key is not possible.

if i can iterate of the json objects key with correct order,that would serve the purpose though.

Comment: Unless the server separately sends you an array of the keys in the “correct” order, there is no way to determine what correct even means. As the others stated, he keys of a dictionary have no guaranteed order, so any order is correct from the dictionary’s perspective.

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned you cannot get the ordered data in Dictionary. If possible you can add the "order" key in your JSON like

```
[
  {
    "name": "sample name",
    "order": 1
  },
  {
    "age": "30",
    "order": 1
  },
  {
    "gender": "",
    "male": "",
    "order": 1
  }
]
```

so that based on the order key you can do the sorting.

Comment: as i said,its a third party api and i dont have any handle on it .

if it was on me,i would have sent each key vallue as json array.

Comment: If possible get the logic for ordering the JSON from the third part api and use the same in iOS